# Sticky sidebar that turns into absolute position near the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

i am using a sticky bar that i want to be fixed when scroll to it and when it touches the footer it turns into absolute position

```
if ($('.sidebar').length ) {
var elementPosition = $('.sidebar').offset();
var footerOffset = $(document).height() - $('footer').height() - $('.sidebar').height();
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < footerOffset) {
        $('.sidebar').css('position','fixed').css('top','0px').css('margin','0 0 0 690px');
    } else{
        $('.sidebar').css('position','absolute').css('top',footerOffset + 'px').css('margin','0 0 0 690px');
    }

} else {
    $('.sidebar').css('position','relative').css('top','inherit').css('margin','0 0 0 20px');

}  
});
};
```

but it sometimes works fine and other times it fails to calculate the footerOffset var and make the sidebar goes over the footer

u can check it at 
http://engez-eg.com/aboodnour/screenshots/featured

Comment: It would be better to create a Fiddle.. Maybe you can use my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txgs6vwu/1/) as your starting point..

Comment: i already gave u alink of a working website ... i dun think the problem is in the code its in the way it works ...